# using Hibernate and MS SQL with intelliJ IDEA

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, persistence-unit

I am using Hibernate/JPA 2.0 with SQL Server and IntelliJ IDEA here's a sample code I made to test the connection:

```
public class App {
    public static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select u from UsersEntity as u where u.userId = :userId";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String userId = "1";
        PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistence();
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory("newPersistenceUnit", new HashMap());
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        List<UsersEntity> users = entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY, UsersEntity.class).setParameter("userId", userId).getResultList();
        System.out.println(users);
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

And here's what I receive in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\alt-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\alt-string.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;D:\mobitrack\out\production\web;D:\mobitrack\lib\javax.persistence.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\tools.jar;D:\mobitrack\lib\sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.mobitrack.services.App
26 mars 2013 17:44:18 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
26 mars 2013 17:44:18 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
26 mars 2013 17:44:18 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
26 mars 2013 17:44:18 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
26 mars 2013 17:44:19 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
26 mars 2013 17:44:19 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
26 mars 2013 17:44:19 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
26 mars 2013 17:44:19 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MOBITRACKDB]
26 mars 2013 17:44:19 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
```

When debugging I found that it stops at:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory("newPersistenceUnit", new HashMap());
```

Knowing that "newPersistenceUnit" is the name of my persistence unit.

**Edit:**
Yes it works outside IDEA. And when I use the console in IDEA to query the data it works.

I tried using the next code:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {

        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {

        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

I receive the same as above and the debugging stops at :

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

**Edit2:**

I used an EntityManager:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("newPersistenceUnit");

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    List<AdminsEntity> result = entityManager.createQuery( "from AdminsEntity",     AdminsEntity.class ).getResultList();
    for ( AdminsEntity event : result ) {
        logged = event;
    }
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return logged;
```

It stops at:

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("newPersistenceUnit");
```

here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="newPersistenceUnit">
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.GroupsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.ZonesEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.AdminsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.AlarmsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.LocationsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.UsersEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.UserGroupsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.UserZonesEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.SettingsEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.MessagesEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.ProfilesEntity</class>
    <class>com.mobitrack.entities.ProfileZonesEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MOBITRACKDB"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class"
                  value="org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work outside of IDEA?

Comment: Could you show yor persistenc.xml? Could you try to create entity manager factory using "standard" method: EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("newPersistenceUnit");

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by the method breakpoints that [slow down debugger](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-23).

Please double check that you don't have any method breakpoints set. Disabling `toString()` evaluation and alternate collections view options in `Settings` | `Debugger` may also improve its performance.